# IE11 and Edge doesn't load background-image for a CSS class, if it's not used immediately, how to fix?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have the following problem in Edge and IE11.

There is a button made as a div:

```
<div class='button loading'></div>
```

Initially it has the class '**loading**', which has an animated spinner image. This works well.

```
 .loading { background-image: url ('loading.gif'); }
```

When page loading and some other actions are completed, the '**loading**' class is changed to '**ready**':

```
<div class='button ready'> </div>
```

It should have another bg image:

```
 .ready { background-image: url ('ready.svg'); }
```

**The problem is that this image (ready.svg) is not shown in background.** What is more, if i call this image in a hidden img element at the end of page, everything works:

```
<img src="ready.svg" style="display:none;" />
```

**It seems to me that IE11 and Edge are not loading or not applying an image to the background of a div, if it's not used immediately on page load.** Can it be so? Who faced something like this, and how to get rid of this behaviour?

Comment: Did you try the same in any other browsers?

Comment: Related: [On class update, SVG image as background in CSS does not appear in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33949894/1016716)

Comment: Yes, another browsers have no such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a timeout to the dynamic class addition solved this in IE and Edge for me (I am using jQuery).

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#element').addClass('loading');
},1);
```

Not totally sure why! My class was being added on on a form submit event, so maybe the request was being prevented?! Hope this helps someone.